# Problem with getting clicked element after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-font-api

I'm coding a site that displays all fonts from `google-fonts` by using they api. I'm getting those fonts using ajax and they are displaying good, but when then i try to give click event to all p tags (each contains one font) and display them in console by `using console.log($(this))` it shows something that looks like ajax object.

```
$(() => {
    $(".press").click(() => {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=MyApiKey'
        }).done(function (response) {
            let items = response.items;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                const font = items[i];
                let fontFamily = font.family;
                $("div.fonts").append('<p class="font" id="'+i+'">'+fontFamily+'</p>');
                $("p#"+i).click(() => {
                    console.log($(this));
                });
                if (i === 723) {
                    const font = items[i];
                    let fontFamily = font.family;
                    let fontUrl = font.files.regular;
                    $("body").append("<style>@font-face {font-family: "+fontFamily+";src: url("+fontUrl+");}</style>")
                    let div = document.querySelector("#div5");
                    $("#div5").css("font-family", fontFamily);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You're using an arrow function, so it *closes over* `this` rather than having it set by how it's called. Use a traditional function instead for the `click` handler. Or, if you prefer, keep using an arrow function but accept the event parameter and use its `currentTarget` property, which is the same thing `this` normally is (the element on which you hooked the event).
2. You're using an invalid selector for the paragraphs. A CSS ID selector cannot start with a digit. jQuery lets you get away with it if you use a pure ID selector like `#1` because it optimizes that to a `getElementById` call, but when you do a compound selector like `p#1`, it fails. Add a prefix, like `x`, to the IDs and to the ID selectors — or better yet, just look up the event handler on the `p` directly rather than looking it up again.

Something like this (see `***` comments):

```
$(() => {

    $(".press").click(() => {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=MyApiKey'
        }).done(function (response) {
            let items = response.items;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                const font = items[i];
                let fontFamily = font.family;
                // *** Directly hook up the event handler, no need for the `id` attribute
                $('<p class="font">'+fontFamily+'</p>')
                    .click(function() { // *** Use a traditional function
                        console.log($(this));
                    })
                    .appendTo("div.fonts");
                if (i === 723) {
                    const font = items[i];
                    let fontFamily = font.family;
                    let fontUrl = font.files.regular;
                    $("body").append("<style>@font-face {font-family: "+fontFamily+";src: url("+fontUrl+");}</style>")
                    let div = document.querySelector("#div5");
                    $("#div5").css("font-family", fontFamily);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `this` is refering to something else. Instead, we can pass the event object to our `.click` function to grab the element that was clicked and from there get the `currentTarget` property.

For example:

```
$("p#"+i).click((event) => {
   console.log(event.currentTarget);
});
```